# React / Create an error boundary that resets its children

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I am trying to create an error boundary that will display a toast message, log the error to the console and reset the its children. Say I have this code:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <ComponentThrowingAnError prop1="1" />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

So when `ComponentThrowingAnError` throws an error I'd like `ErrorBoundary` to catch it, log it and show a toast message and then reset / re-render `<ComponentThrowingAnError />` with `prop1="1"`. What I mean with reset / re-render is that if my ErrorBoundary is just implemented like this:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(error: Error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.error("An error occured. Please check the console.");
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

its children will still be broken, so the error gets re-thrown until the entire application breaks. Instead, I'd like to have the error boundary discard its children and re-render them, so that they get resetted to `<ComponentThrowingAnError prop1="1" />`.

Is that possible or is there another way to achieve

- Catching and logging the error
- And the resetting the children to their initial states / props?

Oh I forgot, of course, when the error gets thrown because the props cause them, that will still be an issue of course, but I don't want to account for that here. I want to catch errors occurring from inside the children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, you could do something like:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { errorCount: 0 }

  componentDidCatch() {
    this.setState((state) => ({ errorCount: state.errorCount + 1 }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={this.state.errorCount}>
        {this.props.children}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Changing "key" allow you to re-mount the component. You will still see the development error overlay in development mode, just press "ESC" when that happen.

Comment: not a good idea to use "key". you are getting rid of one problem and making another problem for yourself. by using "key" you are forcing remounting of the descendants, kills performance, lead to unexpected behaviors, you may end up loosing states /react animations.

Comment: @KyloRen Are you sure? You are only causing a re-render per error caught which would have removed the children anyway, no?

Comment: @KevinBeal why would children get remove? the point i as trying to make was the  part {this.props.children} will get completely re-rendered when errorCount changes. why would we want that?(think if the {this.props.children} is a large component ), even though you want to show the errors or error count, more gracious way is to control the display at lower level of childern(may be css property for display, visibility etc.).